# Do I need to load JQuery to make this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down boxes that represent year intervals. The user will select a year from the first one (say 2002), and the next drop down box will automatically be filled with years that equal or are greater than the first (2002 and above). I believe I have the correct javascript code (year.js).

Here it is:

```
$("#first").change(function(){
    var val = $("#first option:selected").html();
    $("#second").html("");
    var d = new Date();
     var n = d.getFullYear();

    for (i=val; i<=n;i++){
        $("#second").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
    }
});
```

Here is part of my html form code:

```
<body>
<script src="year.js"></script>

<select id= "first">
// Here, I gather my years from my database 
</select>


<select id= "second">
</select>
```

When I run this, Nothing happens with my second drop down menu. Do I need to load something else into my code like JQuery? If so, how do I do that? Sorry, I am not very familiar with JQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$("#first").change(function(){});` is a call to a jQuery function, so you'll need to load jQuery for it to work. You'll find lots of documentation at [jQuery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: Where did you get the code from?

Comment: I had help with part of the javascript code. But I have used it on JSFiddle and it seems to work.

Comment: @user2562125 give the link of fiddle .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YNuna/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you need to load `jQuery library` to use jQuery function.

you must load the `jQuery library` before using it's function.

example

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> //a local version 
    or
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.js"></script>
<script src="year.js"></script>
```

Download jQuery library from http://jquery.com/download/

**Updated** after OP's comment about http://jsfiddle.net/YNuna/1/

you have laoded `jQuery library` in fiddle.I have marked it with `red color` in the image below.

[image]

also wrap you code in `$(document).ready(function ()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#first").change(function () {
        var val = $("#first option:selected").html();
        $("#second").html("");
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getFullYear();

        for (i = val; i <= n; i++) {
            $("#second").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So if I use your second <script> code for JQuery, I don't need to download it? I am trying that and it isn't working. Should I put it in the head or the body?

Comment: @user2562125 yeah you don't need to download if you using the second script and also warp you code in ` $(document).ready(function ()` see answer.

Comment: I've got my <select> elements within <p> tags. Is that why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

If you're copy-pasting javascript code from anywhere and you see a `$` sign, a good rule of thumb is that it uses jQuery.

See here for adding it to your page: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/